# best jQuery AJAX multiple uploader

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Any suggestions?

Possibly something very interactive that I can multiple-select files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading files with Ajax isn't possible due to security reasons. There is a work-around with posting files to an iframe, but you can't select multiple files this way.

The solution lies in flash. The two most common flash uploaders are:

swfupload - http://swfupload.org/

uploadify - http://www.uploadify.com/ (jQuery only)

Answer (score 3):

plupload - http://www.plupload.com/

supports multiple uploads in every type except basic html4

Allows uploads using HTML5, gears, flash, silverlight, BrowserPlus or plain on HTML4

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Uber-Uploader](http://uber-uploader.sourceforge.net/) I have used it and it works well with a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload class in Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

At this point i'd stay away from flash plugins.
I'd use HTML5 uploader instead like this one:[valums uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)

Sure - you'll be able to select multiple files in modern browsers only, otherwise - it'll be  file by file. but hey - if person doesn't care about upgrading to newer browsers - they really probably don't know how to Ctrl+click anyways.

Flash doesn't send cookies correctly (it sends IE cookies even if you use firefox or google chrome). So - you'll lose cookies and thus sessions. There is a workaround - to send PHPSESSID in POST requests - but it simply opens door wide open for session fixation.