# asp.net image upload control (bonus - allows users to crop image before saving)

Tags: asp.net, image, upload

We have a scenario where we would like to allow our users to upload images to the site. We are running on ASP.Net.

A quick search did not result in anything good. It would be great if the control is free/open source but we do not mind paying a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

I highly reccomend [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html).

I've [posted an article on how to use JCrop and image resizing to let users crop and resize dynamically](http://nathanaeljones.com/573/combining-jcrop-and-server-side-image-resizing/). The example uses about 11 lines of javascript, and you can add 2 or 3 lines of C# to save the dynamically generated image to disk.

If you [download the imageresizing.net module](http://imageresizing.net/download), you can take a look at a sample project that uploads and resizes/crops. (Located in Samples\ComplexWebApplication)

File uploading is the easy part - there are lots of options if you want to upload multiple files... [This SO article lists several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611576/best-jquery-ajax-multiple-uploader).

Answer (score 1):

The following links give the idea for this:
http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ImageCroppingControl.aspx

Now, You can customize fileupload control.

Comment: After going through a bunch, I liked these 2:
 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/imgAreaSelect
http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/
 
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Comment: @NikhilSinghal:I am working on the crop functionality where the user uploads an image using file upload. Could u pls elaborate on  how u were able to customize the code